# Why choose typedef'd unnamed struct over regular struct definition?

Tags: c++, struct

I am using a library, and it has multiple structs defined like this in its header

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int gid;
    unsigned int tilesetIndex;
    unsigned int tileFlatIndex;
    bool flipX, flipY, flipDiagonal;
} TmxLayerTile;
```

and I am wondering why is it so, instead of `struct TmxLayerTile {...};`? I understand that there is difference in C, that the former would allow using it with `TmxLayerTile` instead of `struct TmxLayerTile`, but for it being in C++, are these completely identical?

I understand this is pretty much semantics, but it got me curious.

Comment: It's the `C` way of doing things.

Comment: It was the C-way.

Comment: so is the answer 'just because'?

Comment: Perhaps the library wants to be usable from C, or at least have its core types being compatible? That would be an actual reason.

Comment: this question is duplicate
( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: @V.Panchenko you are correct! Next time you can `flag` the question for closure instead via the flag link below the question. I'm not sure if you did that this time.